# How to resolve the error when posting a new node with Image Field and Entity Reference?

Tags: 7, services

I'm trying to create a new node using Drupal 7 + [Services](https://www.drupal.org/project/services) 3. The node type is 'activity_photo' has an image field, and a reference to a node. This is what I'm posting to the service

```
{
 "type":"activity_photo",
 "field_node_reference":{
 "und":[{
 "target_id":"x (1273)"
 }]
 },
 "field_photo":{
 "und":[{
 "fid":"20077"
 }]
 }
}
```

The response is status 200:

```
{"nid":null,"uri":...}
```

My error log shows the following:

> Notice: Undefined index: display_field in file_field_widget_value()
>
> Warning: end() [function.end]: Passed variable is not an array or object in file_managed_file_validate()
>
> Notice: Undefined index: nid in _node_resource_create()

Any help on how to proceed?

Answer (score 1):

In the end I changed the entity reference field to select list and posted like this:

```
{
 "title":"test",
 "type":"activity_photo",
 "language":"und",
 "field_node_reference":{
 "und":[1273]
 },
 "field_photo":{"und":[{"fid":"8880"}]}
}
```

also, I found my own modules was implementing [`hook_form_alter`](https://api.drupal.org/hook_form_alter) for this form, and this had further complications to be addressed to get it to work. So any `hook_form_alter` is something to remember when looking for similar problems.